# No puedo añadir un background-image en header

Tags: html, css

Estoy tratando de insertar una imagen en el header pero no la muestra, **en cambio si la inserto en una clase creada por mi si la muestra**. ¿Por qué será?

HTML

```
<body>
<header>
    <div class="header-box">
        <h1>Diego Donoso</h1>
        <h2>Analista Programador</h2>
        <a href="#">Contáctame</a>
    </div>
</header>
</body>
```

CSS

```
header{
  background-image: url(/assets/images/banner1.webp);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
}
.header-box{
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-image: url(/assets/images/banner1.webp);
}
```

ROOT directorio organización:

```
portafolioweb (carpeta principal)
    - index.html
    -> assets (carpeta)
        -> images (sub carpeta)
            -banner1.webp (imagen que no se muestra)
        -> css (sub carpeta)
            -style.css
```

Si me la muestra en .header-box asumo que la ruta está bien pero no me la muestra de fondo de pantalla en el header entonces no entiendo que está pasando.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Tu ".header-box" tiene posición absoluta, por ello la caja que lo contiene no tiene tamaño.
Prueba a quitar dicho posicionamiento y verás que sí aparece la imagen de fondo, realmente "header" al no tener ningun elemento que empuje sus límites, tiene un height igual a 0.
Si lo que buscabas con el posicionamiento absoluto era centrar vertical y horizontalmente la caja "header-box" te recomiento que utilices flex para este cometido.

```css
header{
  background-image: url(https://kps.com/content/dam/wine/images/1920x480/1920x480_business_Stellenangebote_Teaser_Varianten10.jpg/_jcr_content/renditions/cq5dam.web.1920.2890.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 25px 0;
}
.header-box{
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.75);
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 0 25px 25px;
}
.header-box a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body>
<header>
    <div class="header-box">
        <h1>Diego Donoso</h1>
        <h2>Analista Programador</h2>
        <a href="#">Contáctame</a>
    </div>
</header>
</body>
```

Comment: @diego-donoso te dejo un ejemplo ejecutable para que puedas verlo

Answer (score 0):

Los h1 y h2 son elementos de tipo bloque y aunque no asignes ninguna propiedad en especifico, dichos elemento se muestran y ocupan todo el ancho disponible dentro del contenedor, esto permite que la imagen de fondo se muestre.

Todo lo contrario ocurre con tu header que al no tener ningún elemento dentro del mismo no muestra la imagen de fondo; recuerda que posicionaste de forma absoluta la clase "header-box" y esto la saca fuera del contexto de "header".

La solución mas practica es asignarle a tu "header" una altura "height" para que se muestre, así no tenga ningún contenido dentro de la misma; pero la clase "header-box" todavía estaría fuera del header.